# Random Number generation Issues

Tags: java, random

This question was asked in my interview.
random(0,1) is a function that generates integers 0 and 1 randomly.
Using this function how would you design a function that takes two integers a,b as input and generates random integers including a and b.

I have No idea how to solve this.

Comment: Think of the supplied function as generating random bits. How would you generate a random n-bit number with it?

Comment: Apart from a and b occurring with non-zero probability, is there any particular limitation as to the distribution of the random integers?

Comment: I did not ask that to interviewer but he meant any number should be selected with equal probability b/w a and b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this easily by bit logic (E,g, a=4 b=10)

1. Calculate difference b-a (for given e.g. 6)
2. Now calculate ceil(log(b-a+1)(Base 2)) i.e. no of bits required to represent all numbers b/w a and b
3. now call random(0,1) for each bit. (for given example range will be b/w 000 - 111)
4. do step 3 till the number(say num) is b/w 000 to  110(inclusive)  i.e. we need only 7 levels since b-a+1 is 7.So there are 7 possible states a,a+1,a+2,... a+6 which is b.
5. return num + a.

Comment: I like this idea but I think there should be a better for doing this.

Comment: This is indeed a good way to do it. The issue with this is that there's up to almost 50% chance of reaching step 4 and needing to return to step 3 (for example, when needing a number between 0 and 8, you end up generating numbers from 0 to 15, so 9-15 require repeats), so the total time for the operation is X (step 3 time) + .5X + .25*X + .125X etc., approaching 2X. It's difficult to avoid that overhead without making some results more likely than others, which is why this kind of thing is a common interview question - discussing the problem requires some level of insight.

Comment: There is actually an easy (and intuitive) way to avoid that overhead while maintaining a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I hate this kind of interview Question because there are some
answer fulfilling it but the interviewer will be pretty mad if you use them. For example,

```
Call random, 
if you obtain 0, output a
if you obtain 1, output b
```

A more sophisticate answer, and probably what the interviewer wants is

```
init(a,b){
  c = Max(a,b)
  d = log2(c) //so we know how much bits we need to cover both a and b
}

Random(){
 int r = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i< d; i++)
    r = (r<<1)| Random01();
 return r;
 }
```

You can generate random strings of 0 and 1 by successively calling the sub function.

Answer (score 0):

So we have `randomBit()` returning 0 or 1 independently, uniformly at random and we want a function `random(a, b)` that returns a value in the range `[a,b]` uniformly at random. Let's actually make that the range `[a, b)` because half-open ranges are easier to work with and equivalent. In fact, it is easy to see that we can just consider the case where `a == 0` (and `b > 0`), i.e. we just want to generate a random integer in the range `[0, b)`.

Let's start with the simple answer suggested elsewhere. (Forgive me for using c++ syntax, the concept is the same in Java)

```
int random2n(int n) {
   int ret = n ? randomBit() + (random2n(n - 1) << 1) : 0;
}
int random(int b) {
    int n = ceil(log2(b)), v;
    while ((v = random2n(n)) >= b);
    return v;
}
```

That is-- it is easy to generate a value in the range `[0, 2^n)` given `randomBit()`. So to get a value in `[0, b)`, we repeatedly generate something in the range `[0, 2^ceil(log2(b))]` until we get something in the correct range. It is rather trivial to show that this selects from the range `[0, b)` uniformly at random.

As stated before, the worst case expected number of calls to `randomBit()` for this is `(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...) ceil(log2(b)) = 2 ceil(log2(b))`. Most of those calls are a waste, we really only need `log2(n)` bits of entropy and so we should try to get as close to that as possible. Even a clever implementation of this that calculates the high bits early and bails out as soon as it exits the wanted range has the same expected number of calls to `randomBit()` in the worst case.

We can devise a more efficient (in terms of calls to `randomBit()`) method quite easily. Let's say we want to generate a number in the range `[0, b)`. With a single call to `randomBit()`, we should be able to approximately cut our target range in half. In fact, if `b` is even, we can do that. If `b` is odd, we will have a (very) small chance that we have to "re-roll". Consider the function:

```
int random(int b) {
    if (b < 2) return 0;
    int mid = (b + 1) / 2, ret = b;
    while (ret == b) {
         ret = (randomBit() ? mid : 0) + random(mid);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This function essentially uses each random bit to select between two halves of the wanted range and then recursively generates a value in that half. While the function is fairly simple, the analysis of it is a bit more complex. By induction one can prove that this generates a value in the range `[0, b)` uniformly at random. Also, it can be shown that, in the worst case, this is expected to require `ceil(log2(b)) + 2` calls to `randomBit()`. When `randomBit()` is slow, as may be the case for a true random generator, this is expected to waste only a constant number of calls rather than a linear amount as in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomBetween(int a, int b){
int x = b-a;//assuming a is smaller than b
float rand = random();
return a+Math.ceil(rand*x);
}
```